# Google Maps API v3, Global Variables

Tags: google-maps, global-variables

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to javascript, but I wanted to place a Google Map of my location on my website, and to have a simple form where visitors can enter their address and the directions would be shown. I've got it working OK, but it's been mentioned that there are too many global variables created by the script. The globals are as follows:

`calcRoute`, `directionsDisplay`, `directionsService`, `google`, `initialize`, `map`

If I try to make any of these globals local instead, it breaks the script, and the map doesn't display. Here's the js I have written:

```
var initialize = function strict() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(53.503716, -1.12975);
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: mapCenter
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    locationPin = "images/location_pin.png";
    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: mapCenter,map: map,icon: locationPin});
    };

var calcRoute = function strict() {
    routeStart = document.getElementById("start").value;
    calculatedRoute = {origin: routeStart, destination: mapCenter, travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING};
    directionsService.route(calculatedRoute, function (routeStart, mapCenter) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(routeStart);
    calculatedRoute = routeStart.routes[0].legs[0];
    });
};
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
```

As far as I can see, the globals I mentioned are required by the Google Maps API and they have to be globals. Any advice on this would be very gratefully welcomed.

Comment: Show us the exactly error :D

Comment: There isn't an error, the script does what it's supposed to. I showed this code to another community  and they said that there were too many global variables. I ran the code through JSLint, and it showed the variables I listed. What I am asking is whether this is an issue, and if the code can be better written?

Comment: from question i really dont know what you need. Can you explain it more?

Comment: really dont know if problem is too many global variables. You can rewrite it into class probably... but i dont see problem if script is working as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK!

But, if you don't want that this variable be global, insert your code at a function, like:

```
(function () { 
    //your code 
}());
```

Using this, the variables will be at a scope, but in your case, it dosen't make difference...

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm still getting to grips with Javascript, so when a few people said the code was bad because it generated too many global variables I was worried.